# Different custom install locations for pip2 and pip3

Tags: python, pip

When using pip with the --user flag, the default installation location is ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages, where X.Y specifiy the version of python.  This allows for separation of packages installed using pip2 from those installed via pip3.

However, when using a pip.conf file to specify a target installation directory, I've only seen a global setting such as this:

```
[global]
target=/data/user/pip
```

This works, but doesn't separate packages installed by pip2 from those installed via pip3 which can cause issues.  Is there a way to specify different locations for packages installed via pip2 and those installed via pip3?

Comment: Why don't you use virtualenv? With it you will be able to install packages per project (be it python2 or python3)

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov I do use virtualenv quite extensively, but there are some packages that I'd like always installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no possibility to handle version-specific stuff in the `pip` config. [The current decision about this is](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2417#issuecomment-77462826):

> ...it doesn't appear to be something we actually need.

However, the user installation target is actually configured not via `--target`, but via the `PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable. This means that you can pass the user base from env, for example `PYTHONUSERBASE=/some/dir pip install --user pkgname`. If you want to persist the custom user base dir, I'd go with an alias. Example for `bash`: in your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`, add:

```
alias pip2='PYTHONUSERBASE=/tmp/pip2 pip2'
alias pip3='PYTHONUSERBASE=/tmp/pip3 pip3'
alias pip3.7='PYTHONUSERBASE=/tmp/pip3.7 pip3.7'
# etc
```

Save the file, reload with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or simply open a new terminal. Now

```
$ pip2 install --user pkgname
```

will install to `/tmp/pip2` etc.

Comment: The pip.conf file seems cleaner but it seems I've been outvoted so this will do the trick.  Thanks!